# How can I stop this JSP if the browser has stopped?

Tags: java, jsp, browser

I created a JSP which will create a potentially infinite amount of output.

When I told the browser to stop, the browser stopped, but my console told me that the JSP's servlet kept going and going and going.

I'm wondering whether and how I could modify this code so that it will stop if the browser stops receiving data:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"  errorPage="ExcessOutputErrorPage.jsp" %>
<%@ page import="de.svenjacobs.loremipsum.LoremIpsum" %>
<%@ page buffer="8kb" autoFlush="true" %>

<%! 
    private int dumpCount = 0;

    private String nextDump()
    {
        dumpCount++;

        String dumpHeader = "Dumping " + dumpCount + " paragraphs"; 
        String dump = "<h2>" + dumpHeader + "</h2>";
        LoremIpsum loremIpsum = new LoremIpsum();

        System.out.println(dumpHeader);

        for (int i=0; i<dumpCount; i++)
        {
            dump += "<p>" + loremIpsum.getParagraphs(1) + "</p>";
        }

        return dump;
    }
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Large Amount of Text</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Large Amount of Text</h1>
    <% 
        boolean doDump = true;
        while (doDump) 
        { 
            out.println(nextDump());
            out.flush();
        } 
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should eventually be getting a "broken pipe" kind of IOException. But there is some buffering going on, both in the servlet container, and in any web server you may have in front. I doubt that you can do more than call `flush` (which you are already doing).

Comment: I've let it run for a very very long time and it doesn't stop.  I also discovered something interesting:  If I visit the page again, whether the same browser or a different browser, the page rendered depends how much the servlet has progressed since it originally started.

Comment: Discovered a couple more interesting things.  If I try to browse to the page in a second browser window while leaving the first browser window open, nothing will render in the second browser window until I close or stop the first browser window.  If two browsers are waiting, it will send some content to one and some to the other, but no content to both.  If three browsers are waiting, it only sends to one.  But if four are waiting, three get content.  If two are receiving content, they must both be terminated before another one (or maybe two) will start receiving content.

Comment: Played with the code to discover that the failure of new pages to start back at 1 paragraph is a result of having <%! private int dumpCount = 0; %>  If I declare dumpCount outside <%! %>, and adjust code accordingly, new pages will start at paragraph 1, but all other described problems remain.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the process from Browser, you may want to look at AJAX. Expose the loremIpsum object and have the AJAX code call back to your server in order to continue updating your screen.

Right now with an infinite loop running full time on your application server, multiple requests can come in and severely slow down the server.

based on what I can see of the code you posted, the loremIpsum object doesn't appear to be specific to the user, so you should be safe to use AJAX in order to move the looping and majority of the work off the server resources and into JavaScript/AJAX.

Comment: Interesting idea, but the loop isn't actually supposed to be infinite -- I expected it to stop when the browser disconnected.  This doesn't however seem to be the case and I'm trying to figure out how to stop it.  I suppose I could put some JavaScript into the webpage telling it to phone home when the user leaves the page, but that would rely on the browser having JavaScript enabled.